# aws esc windows container pseudoTerminal cloudwatch ouput with strange chars

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, windows-container, ecs-taskdefinition

I am running AWS ESC (Windows EC2).

The container with `-t` runs well on my machine. The task definition has `pseudoTerminal: true` so that it will run `-t` on Windows EC2.

The output logged into CloudWatch log group has strange chars beside the correct data.

[image]

Note: the output is fine when running without `-t` (`pseudoTerminal: null`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my container output using the `xterm control sequences`.

https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Definitions